# MySQL unique index by multiple fields

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, unique-index

We have a special kind of table in our DB that stores the history of its changes in itself. So called "self-archived" table:

```
CREAT TABLE coverages (
   id INT, # primary key, auto-increment
   subscriber_id INT,
   current CHAR,  # - could be "C" or "H".
   record_version INT,
   # etc.
);
```

It stores "coverages" of our subscribers. Field "current" indicates if this is a current/original record ("C") or history record ("H").

We could only have one current "C" coverage for the given subscriber, but we can't create a unique index with 2 fields (*subscriber_id and current*) because for any given "C" record there could be any number of "H" records - history of changes.

So the index should only be unique for *current == 'C'* and any subscriber_id.

That could be done in Oracle DB using something like "materialized views": where we could create a materialized view that would only include records with *current = 'C'* and create a unique index with these 2 fields: *subscriber_id, current*.

The question is: **how can this be done in MySQL?**

Comment: What is the purpose for the unique index? What can't you do with a non-unique index? This sounds a bit like a premature optimization ...

Comment: We have multiple application servers (web) that could try inserting the same record simultaneously (and it actually happens). We need to prevent duplicates in coverages table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `NULL` values.  If you use `NULL` instead of "`H`", [MySQL will ignore the row when evaluating the `UNIQUE` constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html):

```
A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be
distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that
matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply to NULL values except
for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple
NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
```

Now, this is cheating a bit, and it means that you can't have your data exactly as you want it.  So this solution may not fit your needs.  But if you *can* rework your data in this way, it should work.

Comment: For some reason I didn't think of NULLs :) This would work really great for us, at least as a short-term solution... Long term we are going to split this one table into two: coverages and coverage_history. THANK YOU SO MUCH, SIR!!!